# Changed display driver, boot now gets stuck

Tags: boot, nvidia

On a laptop with a Nvidia GeForce 9200M GPU, I wanted to move to the [recommended] (version-current) from the version post-release updates ussing Additional Drivers. Everything went ok during the installation, and after that I restarted my PC. The boot stops at this:
![image]

I can't CTRL + ALT + 1 to go to a terminal, and it hangs there for at least 5 minutes but if I press the power button, it goes on it's way to shut down the laptop without issues, and displaying the normal messages it shows when closing.

How can I make this to work, cause I'd really hate to reinstall Ubuntu again (especially since it seems that I bust my install once every 2 months)

I last time this happend to me, I could get it to work if I chose another version of linux in the grub menu. Using the recovery mode didn't help

Answer (score 1):

well I managed to deal with it my myself (I basically did a victory dance afterwards). If you can't use Ctrl + Alt + F1 (or other keys from F2 - F6) reboot in recovery (option from grub).

From that menu, choose Enable Networking. At this point I encountered a problem as my wifi adapter had 3rd party drivers and always blocked the recovery. If you too have this, simply disable your adaptor and use your Ethernet interface for this recovery. Besides enabling the network access (needed further along this recovery), it also mounts as read/write all your partitions in fstab.

Next go to "Drop to root shell prompt". Enter the following commands:

You should first check what you have installed on your computer

> > `dpkg -l | grep nvidia-*`
> >
> > `apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*`

This will delete programs installed starting with the name "nvidia-". I don't know if you actually need to delete them all, but I wanted to be sure (I also held a grudge on the drivers and wanted to see them burn)

> > `apt-get install nvidia-commons`
> >
> > `apt-cache search nvidia-*`

The first command will install nvidia-commons and the second searches the apt cache for packages you must install. My GPU had three possible drivers (of which only one is actually works).For me it was `nvidia-170-updates`

> > apt-get install nvidia-170-updates

Btw, there was no need to use `sudo` since I was in the root shell